# Python ncclient unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed ncclient 0.5.0 on python 3.4.  I cannot even get as far as connecting to a device without getting the error below:

```
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are no supported.
Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

My connection looks like so:

```
m = manager.connect(host='10.159.11.53',
                    port=830,
                    username='xxxxx',
                    password='xxxxxxxx',
                    hostkey_verify=False,
                    unknown_host_cb=uknown_host_cb,
                    device_params={'name':'default'},
                    timeout=90)
```

Any ideas?  Is this just not Python 3.4 ready as claimed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace. Seems like the API expects some (or all) of the arguments to by `bytes` instead of `str`, but it's hard to tell which without the full trace.

Comment: Find Out which Parameter is faulty. Then use the decoding. 'string'.decode('utf-8'). But i'm Not sure, i'm always unsure about the encoding stuff myself!

Comment: Just checked... This works just fine in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

ncclient 0.5.0 supports Python 2.6 <= version < 3.0 as per the document.
Upgrade to the lastest ncclient version to use Python3.